# a query to find duplicates but exclude set

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregation

I have a table with following columns

```
Emp_id
Work_date
element
```

I want a query (modified version of below query) which will return a single row if there are more than 1 row for given work_date and employee id (GROUP BY EMP_ID and WORK_DATE) in above table. So I have written query like:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, WORK_DATE  FROM myTable
where WORK_DATE = :p_WorkDate
GROUP BY EMP_ID, WORK_DATE
HAVING COUNT (1) > 1
```

For example:

```
EMP_ID  WORK_DATE
1       1/1/2013
1       1/1/2013
2       1/1/2013
```

Query should return as follows if I pass 1/1/2013 for :p_WorkDate:

```
1    1/1/2013
```

Basically I am trying to find if there are more than 1 row by EMP_ID and WORK_DATE but there is additional requirement what ELEMENT column contains -  if it contains values from a set (element1 + element2) or (element3 + element4).

The additional requirements (following) depend upon what element column contains (if the rows have values from set).

1) There are 2 rows with same emp_id and work_date and one of the element column is element1 and other element column is element2 (a set of element1 and element 2)

For example:

```
EMP_ID  WORK_DATE element
1   1/1/2013  element1
1   1/1/2013  element2
```

the query should not return any row because     even if there are two rows, it is a set (element1 and elelement2)

2) There are 2 rows with same emp_id and work_date and one of the element column is element3 and other element column is element4 (a set of element3 and element 4)

For example:

```
EMP_ID  WORK_DATE element
1   1/1/2013  element3
1   1/1/2013  element4
```

The query should not return any row because     even if there are two rows, it is a set (element3 and element 4)

3) If there are 2 rows with same emp_id and work_date and which is not a set as above should return a row

For example:

```
EMP_ID  WORK_DATE element
1   1/1/2013  element1
1   1/1/2013  xxx
```

(same result if element column had element2 instead of element1)

Query should return as follows if I pass 1/1/2013 for :p_WorkDate:

```
1    1/1/2013
```

4) If there are more than 2 rows with same emp_id and work_date, no matter what element column contains, it should return a row.

For example:

```
EMP_ID  WORK_DATE element
1   1/1/2013  element1
1   1/1/2013  element2
1   1/1/2013 xxx
```

Query should return as follows if I pass 1/1/2013 for :p_WorkDate:

1    1/1/2013

---

Thank you

Comment: Where are these set pairs stored? Also, count(1) is conventionally count(*) -- there is no advantage to count(1), and it's unconventionality is a disadvantage.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - pairs can be hard coded in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go ... I think I got the logic straight:

```
select
  emp_id,
  work_date
from (
  select
    emp_id,
    work_date,
    min(element) min_element,
    max(element) max_element,
    count(*) rows_counted
  from
    mytable
  where
    work_date = :p_workdate
  group by
    emp_id,
    work_date
  having
    count (*) > 1)
where
  rows_counted > 2 or
  (min_element,max_element) not in (select 'element1' el1, 'element2' el2 from dual union all
                                    select 'element3' el1, 'element4' el2 from dual)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a set-within-a-set subquery and you can do all the work in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, WORK_DATE
FROM myTable
where WORK_DATE = :p_WorkDate
GROUP BY EMP_ID, WORK_DATE
HAVING sum(case when element not in ('element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4')
                then 1 else 0
           end) > 0 or
       (sum(case when element in ('element1', 'element2') > 0 and
        sum(case when element in ('element3', 'element4') > 0
       )
```

The logic is.  The first clause in the `having` statement is about any element not in the two sets.  If there is one, then return a row.

The second condition is when there are elements from both sets.  That is the case where you would also return a row.  If all the rows have only elements from one set, then it is ok.

Your rules are ambiguous about a case where there are three rows with a duplicate, such as two `'element1'` and one '`element2'`.  With this formulation it is ok.  Hopefully you see how to extend the `having` clause for your exact situation.